# Google Apps Script: How do I pull data entered today from one spreadsheet and transpose it to another?

Tags: javascript, date, filter, google-apps-script, filtering

Okay, I've been working on this for about a month. I've tried numerous different ways of doing this, and I think I'm close. I'm not an expert, but here is what I'm trying to do. I've created a form that allows me to capture behavior data for my son. (He's autistic, which is why this is important.) I can get the data from the form into a results spreadsheet and I can transfer the data to a new report style pre formatted spreadsheet. What I can't do is filter the dates effectively. My script is below.

```
function onOpen() {
var rawdata=SpreadsheetApp.openById("0AtkuL_H_DshvdFU5U1dBLVI1NWhlWXdSNjBXOHdIaUE");
var sheet1=rawdata.getSheetByName("FormResponses");
var maxrows=sheet1.getMaxRows();
var lastcol = sheet.getLastColumn();
var vals=sheet1.getRange(1,1,maxrows,1).getValues();

  var date = new Date();
  var newDate = date.setDate(date.getDate()+1);
  var Sdate=Utilities.formatDate(date,"GMT-0400","yyyy:MM:dd");
  var newerDate=Utilities.formatDate(newDate,"GMT-0400","yyyy:MM:dd");

var filter=ArrayLib.filterByDate(vals,1,Sdate,newerDate);
var range1 = sheet1.getRange(1,1,filter,lastcol);
var values = range1.getValues();
var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0AtkuL_H_DshvdGxWNGJ0ZjA2VU5zV01iaVNacDZQYWc")
var sheet2 = target.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var range2 = sheet2.getRange(4,1,i,7);
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(rawdata);
values
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(target);
range2.setValues(values);
}


//for (var i = 0; i < maxrows; i++) if (Date.parse(vals[i]).valueOf() >= todaydt.valueOf() );
```

The last line is a prior way I tried to filter the dates. That's the part I can't quite get to work. Part of my challenge is that I don't quite understand the "for" command yet. I'm doing the CodeAcademy java course, but since I work, have a family, and don't do this for a living its slow going. I've searched about a thousand websites and tried numerous ways to filter the dates, but I can't get any of them to work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I assume arraylib.filterbydate takes dates but you are passing strings. Try passing dates.
Or just filter by string if that lib allows it. Since you are formatting the date strings as yyyymmdd your string comparisons could work.